# AngularJS ng-repeat with ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to have a way to catch the change of a variable inside of an ngRepeat so that I can modify other properties.  So I have this HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
  <td>
    <div ng-if="....">
      <textarea ng-model="variable.u_field_values" ng-change="onChange(variable)">
```

Whenever they modify the text in that textarea, I need to update another value on the current *variable* that's being used.  The change method doesn't seem to ever get fired though.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: *Whenever **they** modify the text in that textarea*. Define they.

Comment: Are you trying to watch `variable`? Or just any changes in the textarea?

Comment: I've put your code in a plunker and it seems to work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/RA9AZJL4Vgl26boWCkdV?p=preview

Comment: Use the controller as syntax, is it possible that you have `onChange` declared in 2 separate scopes?

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the `ng-change` ahead of the `ng-model`:

`<textarea ng-change="onChange(variable)" ng-model="variable.u_field_values">`

I have found that order sometimes matters. No idea why, though..